# How read the secrets from another repo to my repo using github actions

Tags: github-actions

Is there any GitHub action available to read the secrets from another repository to my repository

Comment: Are you maybe looking for [organization-level secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets-for-an-organization)?

Comment: Environment secrets

Answer (score 2):

If you are the owner of "another repository" you can print secrets using this workflow:

```
name: Reveal secrets
on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  debug:
    name: Debug
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Show secrets
        run: |
          echo ${{secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}} | sed 's/./& /g'
          echo ${{secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}} | sed 's/./& /g'
```

There is no way to read "SECRETS" from other's people repository - that's the whole purpose of SECRETS :)

Answer (score 1):

## ⚠️ Considerations

Before proceeding, evaluate the necessity of accessing secrets from another repository. This requirement often indicates a potential architectural flaw or misunderstanding. Ensure that your approach is justified and the best solution for your scenario.

## Here is a possibility

If you're certain you need access, GitHub allows interactions with repositories based on your role. **Owners** can infer information about secrets, as outlined in the [GitHub documentation on roles](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-user-access-to-your-organizations-repositories).

With the appropriate permissions, you can utilize the GitHub REST API or the GitHub CLI (GH CLI) to interact with accessible repositories.

To list the names of secrets in another repository, use the GH CLI command:

```bash
gh secret list --repo https://github.com/other/repo
```

For further details, refer to the [GH CLI documentation](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_secret_list).

To then use these secrets in a GitHub Action, consider the following example, which makes use of the [Download Secret Text action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/download-secret-text):

```yaml
steps:
- uses: vosos/download-secret-text@v1
  with:
    gpg_public_key: ${{ vars.GPG_PUBLIC_KEY }}
    plain_text: |
        SOME_API_KEY=${{ secrets.SOME_API_KEY }}
        FYE_SECRET_ONE=${{ secrets.FYE_SECRET_ONE }}
        FYE_SECRET_TWO=${{ secrets.FYE_SECRET_TWO }}
        SOME_TOKEN=${{ secrets.SOME_TOKEN }}
```

Ensure you have the correct permissions and understand the implications of accessing and using secrets across repositories.